# How can I publish a Polymer app on GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, polymer, publish, github-pages

I wrote a Polymer app based on their tutorial app and tried publishing it to GitHub Pages. From what I can tell, my folder structure is the same as the one in Polymer GitHub. However, after publishing to GitHub Pages, Polymer's `index.html` and `src` folder are peers of each other under their page's project name (`polymer-starter-kit`).
[Polymer working tutorial page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSBbI.png)

For me, my `index.html` is under the page's project name (`smash-up`), but the `src` folder shows up one level too high. It also does not contain my actual `src` files. And I get an error saying it is looking outside of the smash-up directory to find the `src` folder, which is really weird.

My broken project page:
[image: my broken project page]

So what gives? How do I get it to publish and search under the `smash-up` folder like it's supposed to? My repo is on GitHub: `dalejoel/smash-up`.

Comment: I figured it out.

<link rel="import" href="/src/my-app.html">

The initial '/' character in the href is why. If I remove it, then it finds the files.

Comment: You should add that as an answer to your own question :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been successful in resolving this in my Polymer v2 app by simply changing all the pertinent paths on my source files (index.html and those on my /src/ folder) by putting a leading dot so as to make the path relative.

For example `<link rel="import" href="/src/my-app.html">`

Becomes `<link rel="import" href="./src/my-app.html">`

As you can see, the first path is absolute, while the second is relative to the current working directory.

Checking my browser's development tools Network tab has helped me in monitoring what files were not being fetched properly (404) - from then it was just a matter of fixing all imports, image paths, etc until I got my application to run properly on the free GitHub pages service.